# No value specified for parameter - CrudRepository

Tags: spring, hibernate, postgresql

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer> {

@Query(value = "select u from User u")
List<User> selectAllUsers();

@Query(value = "select u from User u where u.username = ?1")
User findByName(String name);

@Query(value = "select u from User u where u.id = ?1")
User findById(Integer id);

@Modifying
@Transactional(readOnly = false)
@Query("UPDATE User u SET u.friends = ?1 WHERE u.id = ?2")
Integer setNewFriendsForId(Set<User> friends, Integer id);
}
```

Spring provides me with implementation of this interface that is used in class called UserService. But when I try to execute this method I get a really huge stack of exceptions.

```
 userService.setNewFriendsForId(invitingUser.getFriends(), invitingUser.getId());
```

The root cause is:

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: No value specified for parameter 2.
    org.postgresql.core.v3.SimpleParameterList.checkAllParametersSet(SimpleParameterList.java:178)
    org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:246)
    org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:512)
(...)

Any ideas what can be the reason? Select queries work right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason is that collection valued field (u.friends) cannot be updated. In JPA 2.0 specification this is told with following words:

```
update_statement ::= update_clause [where_clause]
update_clause ::= UPDATE entity_name [[AS] identification_variable]  
                  SET update_item {, update_item}*
update_item ::= [identification_variable.]{state_field 
                | single_valued_object_field} = new_value
new_value ::= scalar_expression | simple_entity_expression | NULL
```

Update operation works only for single value fields as in following:

```
UPDATE User u SET u.someSingleValuedField = ?1
```

Comment: So how can I add a new row in database for many-to-many relationship?